# How can I change styling of all Material UI Typography components in single react component without applying a class to every element?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

I'm struggling with the way you apply styles in a React SPA with Material UI components. I have the feeling to have missed some key point in the concept.

Say I have the following `Header` component:

```
const Header = () => (
<AppBar position="fixed" >
  <Toolbar>
    <Link component={RouterLink} to="/">
      <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
        Home
      </Typography>
    </Link>
    <Link component={RouterLink} to="/trainings">
      <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
        Trainings
      </Typography>
    </Link>
  </Toolbar>
</AppBar>
);
```

How can I apply some styling to say all `Typography` components in the `Header` component. I know I can use `makeStyles` with the `useStyles` hook like this:

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    headerText: {
      color: 'white',
    },
  })
);

const Header: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  return (
    <div>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <Link component={RouterLink} to="/">
            <Typography className={classes.headerText} variant="h6" noWrap>
              Home
            </Typography>
          </Link>
          <Link component={RouterLink} to="/trainings">
            <Typography className={classes.headerText} variant="h6" noWrap>
              Trainings
            </Typography>
          </Link>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Header;
```

But that would require me to apply the `className` prop to every element I want to style.

I also came up with the following solution that seems to work, which applies the color to all `h6` elements under the root `div`.

```
const useStyles = makeStyles((theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    headerText: {
      '& h6': {
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
  })
);

const Header: FC = () => {
  const classes = useStyles();
  
  return (
    <div className={classes.headerText}>
      <AppBar position="fixed">
        <Toolbar>
          <Link component={RouterLink} to="/">
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
              Home
            </Typography>
          </Link>
          <Link component={RouterLink} to="/trainings">
            <Typography variant="h6" noWrap>
              Trainings
            </Typography>
          </Link>
        </Toolbar>
      </AppBar>
    </div>
  );
};
```

But all these solutions don't quite feel right^^

Isn't there a way to just say 'I want all `Typography` components in THIS `Header` component to have a `color` of `white`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a `MuiThemeProvider` to make provide a theme object and make your changes there. If you take a look at the [docs](https://material-ui.com/customization/theming/#theme-configuration-variables)

```
const theme = createMuiTheme({
  overrides: {
    // Style sheet name ⚛️
    MuiButton: {
      // Name of the rule
      text: {
        // Some CSS
        color: 'white',
      },
    },
  },
});

// ...
return (
  <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
    <CssBaseline />
    {children}
  </ThemeProvider>
);
```

And for the `Typography` you can find the class names [here](https://material-ui.com/api/typography/#css)

**UPDATE**

If you are searching for a solution to update the `Typography` only in the `AppBar` then you need to style your `AppBar`. You can find the classNames for your required typography in it's API (link above)

```
const useStyles = makeStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiTypography-root': {
      color: 'black'
    }
  }
})

...

const classes=useStyles()
  return (
    <AppBar classes={{root: classes.root}}>
      <Typography>Hello StackBlitz!</Typography>
    </AppBar>
  );
```

Here's a [live example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-7apjfk)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but that would change the styling of all components in the whole app, wouldn't it?

Comment: You are correct @Tobi. I've updated the answer to better suit your particular case.